# Testing javascript closure in jasmine

Tags: javascript, angularjs, testing, typescript, jasmine

I am completely novice at using jasmine. I couldn't figure out how can I write a test case for a JavaScript closure like below.

My code in Typescript is as follows:

```
module FIRST.Mobile.Controllers{
    "use strict";
    class sampletest
    {
        public subtract(a: number, b: number): number {
            return a - b;
        }
    }
}
```

And when converted to JavaScript it becomes:

```
var FIRST;
(function (FIRST) {
    var Mobile;
    (function (Mobile) {
        var Controllers;
        (function (Controllers) {
            "use strict";
            var sampletest = (function () {
                function sampletest() {
                }
                sampletest.prototype.subtract = function (a, b) {
                    return a - b;
                };
                return sampletest;
            })();
        })(Controllers = Mobile.Controllers || (Mobile.Controllers = {}));
    })(Mobile = FIRST.Mobile || (FIRST.Mobile = {}));
})(FIRST || (FIRST = {}));
```

I do not understand if I could test code in a typescript module? 
If yes can some one explain me how could I test the subtract method using jasmine.

Comment: I don't know for sure about typescript, but with es6 and babel I never look into compiled code. I use the same language and structure to test as my src folder is written in. It doesn't seem right to test es5 if you write ts.

Answer (score 0):

The code you provided actually is not related to closures.

You can access the class `sampletest` (I recommend writing it in CamelCase as `SampleTest`) that way: `FIRST.Mobile.Controllers.sampletest`

Your function `subtract()` is here:

```
var t = new FIRST.Mobile.Controllers.sampletest();
t.subtract(5, 3); // returns 2
```